# Guzzle Http Client ambiguous response

Tags: php, symfony, web-scraping, guzzle

Here's my code in a different file

```
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;
$guzzle = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_url' => 'http://pricematch.pk/mobile/samsung-galaxy-s6-80514-price-in-Pakistan']);
$response = $guzzle->get();
$crawler = new Crawler((string)$response->getBody());
echo $crawler->filter('.product-shop-wrapper .price')->text()."\r\n";
```

The url in this one is hardcoded and this one successfully echos the filtered text. When the same url/any url in the each loop in below code comes from a variable

```
$guzzle = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_url' => 'pricematch.pk/mobile-phone-prices-in-pakistan']);

$response = $guzzle->get();

$crawler = new Crawler((string)$response->getBody());
$crawler->filter('.product-name')->each(function ($node,$counter) {
    echo $counter." ".$node->text()."\r\n";
    $url=$node->filter('a')->extract(array('href'))[0]."\r\n";
    echo $url."\r\n";
    $url='http://pricematch.pk'.$url;
    echo $url;
    $guzzle = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_url' => $url]);
    $response = $guzzle->get();
    $crawler = new Crawler((string)$response->getBody());
```

the crawler throws an exception saying the current node list is empty. The href returns a relative url which I append with root url in the above code. I have printed the resultant url a lot many times. The filter throws exception even when the url is same as in **code#1**.
What am I doing wrong? 
**Update 2**: I just found out that data in **code2** crawler is coming from

```
pricematch.pk/mobile-phone-prices-in-pakistan
```

Where it should be coming from

> $url
>   
> What's goin on here?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me. While extracting URL in above code, I concatenated the newline character which got maybe encoded the URL to come out as __ at the end of the URL which basically changed the URL and hence the changed response.